# Simple comparison of prerequisites not working

Tags: python

The task at hand is quite simple, make a short program that asks for a cpsc prerequisite (number 217,219, or 233) and a math prerequisite (217 or 251) and if you have one of those classes as a prerequisite then it should say prerequisites met, if not then prerequisites not met. My code goes as follows (dont laugh, literally the biggest python noob):

```
cpsc=input("Which cpsc course have you taken (only pick one): ")
math=input("which math course have you taken (only pick one): ")

if cpsc==(217 or 219 or 233) and math ==(217 or 251)
    print("prerequisites met")
else:
    print("prerequisites not met")
```

Every input i have it only gives me the else print, i'm assuming its a problem with the comparisons in `cpsc==` and `math==`, what can i do to make this work? any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also tried incorporating lists, to no avail

Comment: Try using `in` instead of `==` in your case.  You would need to use `==` across each number.  You can't group it like that.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! solved by putting in (217 or 219 or 233 in cpsc) and (217 or 251 in math): etc. etc. etc. im truly grateful for you assistance :D

Comment: Heh, while I was improving my edits the earlier one got approved. No matter, they are minor tweaks anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry but i laughed XD

Kidding, but.. Hahaha. Okay, sorry. Let's get to the point.

**Why isn't it giving the desired output?**

Your if statements have a little problem. Try testing this in your interpeter :)

```
a = 233
if a == (217 or 219 or 233):
    print (True)
else:
    print (False)
```

This will print `False`. Do you know why?

Actually, the use of `or` in your case, `(217 or 219 or 233)` is a little off. 
(You can try to evaluate `(217 or 219 or 233)`). Here, You're actually performing a logical comparison,  using [`or`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Flogore.htm) as the operator (click the link, it's in C, but it should be easy to understand).

**To solve this**

You can use the `in` operator, make your 'desired' values a list:

```
if a in [217, 219, 233] and math in [217, 251]:
    #do something
```

**Edit :)**

Ah, yeah. I forgot to mention that the above code will not work just yet. You're missing one more thing.

What's that? It's the fact that `input` always gives you a string. So, if `a` has `"217"` as it's value, it still wouldn't work, because `217` (an integer) is not equal to `"217"` (a string).

To solve this, convert the input to integers with `int()` function.

```
cpsc = int(input("Which cpsc course have you taken (only pick one): "))
math = int(input("which math course have you taken (only pick one): "))
```

That's all.. Hope this helps!

Comment: Be nice -- we were all new once. :)

Comment: Yep. I'm being friendly :) In a great mood today.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the help! but still nothing, for each of the comparisons should i have seperate lines or can i use the and function?

Comment: This should work fine.. i'll update my answer with an example of the if statement. Wait a second

Comment: Thanks for all the help! solved by putting in (217 or 219 or 233 in cpsc) and (217 or 251 in math): etc. etc. etc. im truly grateful for you assistance :D

Comment: Nope, your code hasn't work just yet. That, it will always evaluates to true.

See my updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow and to Python! I'm going to correct a couple of mistakes and explain what you need to know.

```
cpsc=input("Which cpsc course have you taken (only pick one): ")
math=input("which math course have you taken (only pick one): ")

if (cpsc == 217 or cpsc == 219 or cpsc == 233) and (math == 217 or math == 251):
    print("prerequisites met")
else:
    print("prerequisites not met")
```

That should be working code. But why?

- Python block statements (`if`, `while`, `for`, `def`, and so on) must be followed by a colon (`:`).
- Blocks must be indented to work properly.
- The `or` statement doesn't work like that. You need to check each condition individually, or do something like: `if cpsc in [217, 219, 233]`.

Comment: @SethMMorton Already fixed.

Comment: Also, if this is python3.x (as I expect based on the `print` syntax), the input will need to be cast to an `int` to be able to compare to integers.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! solved by putting in (217 or 219 or 233 in cpsc) and (217 or 251 in math): etc. etc. etc. im truly grateful for you assistance :D

Comment: @BabiRodriguezMalbo Aaah! That won't work -- that'll always return `True`. You really want to do it the way I suggested. See @HennyH's answer as to why.

Comment: @BabiRodriguezMalbo That syntax is wrong, you mean `cpsc in (217, 219, 233)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expressions `==(a or b or c ...)` don't behave in the way you'r expecting. The expression `a or b, ...` undergoes what is called short circuit evaluation (you can read more about this). I.e:

```
>>> 1 or 2 or 3
1
```

Essentially each one resolves in this case to the first number in the expression: `217` and `217` in this case. You need:

```
if cpsc in [217, 219, 233] and math in [217 or 251]:
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! solved by putting in (217 or 219 or 233 in cpsc) and (217 or 251 in math): etc. etc. etc. im truly grateful for you assistance :D